# Magento 2: how to change the Order ID's?

Tags: magento2, orders, sql

There is a similar question here: [Magento 2 - What is the correct way to change default Order Id?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101341/magento-2-what-is-the-correct-way-to-change-default-order-id)
However that did not work for me.

The first order in my store has the ID 000000001.
I want that number to start with 2.
I also want to change the last digit, so the next order's ends in 399.

Comment: "I have the same question as X but the answers did not work for me" is not enough to justify a new question. Please update the question with the exact steps that you tried because probably there was a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

go to your database,
enter below query for table sequence_order_1.
sequence_order_1 is used for order id management.

**ALTER TABLE `sequence_order_1` AUTO_INCREMENT=200000399;**

Next order id is start from 200000399.

Comment: In PHPMYADMIN

INSERT INTO `sequence_order_1` (`sequence_value`) VALUES ('1000');

1000 will be the new start number