# Magento 1.9.x - i want to add some text to order number?

Tags: database, prefix

I want to add some prefix to order number.

Our website has 6 stores and i wanna classify which store customer purchase the item.

You know, orders in ebay and amazon already have their own prefix to order number like this

[image]

But orders proceeded in our own website do not have the prefix, just store_id + number

How can i add some text prefix to order number?
I think by using store_id, i can add them but i don't know how to do.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in `config.xml` created in `Namespace/Custom/etc` folder.

Make sure I have created `Namespace_Custom`

```
<sales_order_save_before>
    <observers>
        <customart_ordernumber>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Namespace_Custom_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>customMethod</method>
        </customart_ordernumber>
    </observers>
</sales_order_save_before>
```

Create file in **Model** directory named `Observer.php`

```
class Namespace_Custom_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer {
    public function customMethod( $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();        
        $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $prefix = 'PREFIX-';
        $reservedOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('order')->fetchNewIncrementId($store_id);
        if ($reservedOrderId != '') {
            $order->setIncrementId( $reservedOrderId);
         }

    }
}
```

I hope you will clear the cache and session. then check it.