# Magento 2 How to change the Order number sequence

Tags: magento2

How to change the Order number sequence in Magento2?

The default sequence 000000001, why there is no setting in Magento 2 CP to modify that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 - What is the correct way to change default Order Id?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101341/magento-2-what-is-the-correct-way-to-change-default-order-id)

Comment: i know that solution but it is not working the value of Auto_increment is 5 and the order number is 000000001

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=300005464;

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Do a Setup Script with an InstallData.php and update the sequence there.
2. Install this module https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-customordernumber, i have tried this module in one of my environments and it works (it has the options to change the order number dynamically ). But to be honest i dont like using Observers .
   What i suggest is to go with the Script modification.

Answer (score 0):

You have two places to change:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `dbname` WHERE `name` LIKE 'sequence_order_1';
ALTER TABLE dbname.sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 9000001;

SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `dbname` WHERE `name` LIKE 'sales_order';
ALTER TABLE dbname.sales_order AUTO_INCREMENT = 9000001;
```

This will change both the order 'order_id' and the increment id thats used alot.