# How to shorten the ID order

Tags: magento-2.1

I try to short order number from 11 to 6.

In database I select table **eav_entity_type**

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_entity_type`
```

go to table "**order**" and looking for **increment_pad_length**

[image]

I found that I have to change the record **increment_pad_lenght**

But here I have value 8 (in magento order ID have 11 digitals).

I change this value to 4 and update magento

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

unfortunately I did not receive any result. Any one know how to do?

EDIT:
after database query

```
select * from sales_sequence_meta;
```

I see table sequence_order_1, sequence_order_2, sequence_order_3 etc.
[image]

After edit for example sequence_order_1 I cannot see **AUTO_INCREMENT** record.

EDIT:
After:

```
mysql: select * from sales_sequence_meta;


ALTER TABLE sequence_order_0 AUTO_INCREMENT=7895;
ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7895;
ALTER TABLE sequence_order_2 AUTO_INCREMENT=7895;
ALTER TABLE sequence_order_3 AUTO_INCREMENT=7895;
ALTER TABLE sequence_order_4 AUTO_INCREMENT=7895;
ALTER TABLE sequence_order_5 AUTO_INCREMENT=7895;
ALTER TABLE sequence_order_6 AUTO_INCREMENT=7895;
```

my order ID is still the same.

@Rakesh Varma,
In file /vendor/magento/module-sales-sequence/Model/Sequence.php, on line 19 I have:

```
const DEFAULT_PATTERN  = "%s%'.09d%s";
```

When I edit file: app/etc/di.xml and adding below line:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\DB\Sequence\SequenceInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="pattern" xsi:type="string">%s%'.06d%s</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Get error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Invalid XML in file /home/brandswearxv/ftp/app/etc/di.xml: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document Line: 1233 Extra content at the end of the document Line: 1234 in /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php:151 Stack trace: #0 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(127): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator)) #1 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(282): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('primary') #2 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(142): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->_loadPrimaryConfig(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList), Object(Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverPool), Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Mapper\Dom), 'developer') #3 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/ve in /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php on line 284
```

Comment: Do you want to change order increment_id length? for example `00000001` to `001`?

Comment: Yes, I have to change the length of the order numbers because I have an integrated magento with the sales system and this system does not accept such a long order number. Do you know how to do ?

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101341/magento-2-what-is-the-correct-way-to-change-default-order-id

Comment: @KeyurShah Thanks, but I cannot see one thing (I have updated my post).

Comment: Did you place any new order? to see the effect you need to place a new order and one more thing don't set the same number(as I can see that you set the 7895 for all store ) for all store otherwise it will break

Comment: @KeyurShah, unfortunately, it does not work. I modified the numbers for each store view then I placed the order. Order ID still the same.

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT will change only next increment value of order it will not change increment_pad_lenght. Try my answer I have use that in my project and it is working well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the padding for the order number you have to override default constant

```
DEFAULT_PATTERN
```

which is set in: `/vendor/magento/module-sales-sequence/Model/Sequence.php`, on line 19.
We can change this in a custom module by creating

```
etc/di.xml
```

with the following content:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\DB\Sequence\SequenceInterface">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pattern" xsi:type="string">%s%'.06d%s</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

You can read more details from here... 
https://www.classyllama.com/blog/m2-incrementid

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, I update my topic, can you check? Thanks.

Comment: You have to add di.xml file in under your module...

Comment: ahh and that would solve this problem! Only to which folder should I upload the new creating file di.xml ?  What do you mean "under your module". Thanks

Comment: You have to create your own module and create di.xml file you can use this website to create module... https://mage2gen.com

Comment: You welcome.. let me know if you face other issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this in magento 2.3+ this will work.

Create di.xml in your module

> [namespace] / [modulename] /etc/di.xml

And paste This code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Sequence">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pattern" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[%s%'.06d%s]]></argument>
    </arguments>
</type></config>
```