# Magento 2.1: Change increment ID for new orders

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, increment-id

Is there any way to change increment ID for new orders. For example if current last order ID is **1000**. But for new orders, I want to start it from **1020**

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101341/magento-2-what-is-the-correct-way-to-change-default-order-id

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in database, check for the table **sequence_order_1** and change the **Autoincrement** value as required.

Comment: Is it safe and proper way ?

Comment: I haven't see any other option so far, just take care while handing DB(backup).