# How to change the order number's prefix of a specific store, Magento2

Tags: magento2, orders, multistore, multi-website, prefix

> Magento2.2.4, php7;

I have multiple stores where I want each one of them to have a different order number's prefix. Is there anyway to realize that?

Thanks!

Edit: I'm trying to avoid using raw queries, any other (safer) way ?

Comment: are you using custom module

Comment: check this if it helps - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101341/magento-2-what-is-the-correct-way-to-change-default-order-id

Comment: @rvSingh no i'm not using a custom module.

Comment: @shashank i saw it, i'm trying to avoid using raw queries on db ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manage it like below:

Magento 2 database contains a table name '**sales_sequence_profile**' which has prefix column and every row contains a meta_id which relates with table '**sales_sequence_meta**'.

Table '**sales_sequence_meta**' sequence table names according to stores and type(**order, invoice, shipment, creditmemo, rma**).

- **sequence_order_*** contains the last inserted order ids
- **sequence_shipment_*** contains the last inserted shipment ids
- **sequence_invoice_*** contains the last inserted invoice ids
- **sequence_creditmemo_*** contains the last inserted creditmemo ids
- **sequence_rma_item_*** contains the last inserted rma item ids

Basically this is just for understanding. You need to update the table '**sales_sequence_profile**' and related **sequence** tables.

Comment: Can this be controlled from Magento Commerce Admin ?

Comment: No. You have to do it manually or develop an extension for it.

Comment: @Sukumar Gorai, could you please have a look at my post on the similar but simpler requirement. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325884/magento-2-3-4-how-to-trim-the-order-confirmation-number/325892?noredirect=1#comment466143_325892

Answer (score 1):

You can change this using by changing related store db tables. i.e

if your store id is 1 :

change prefix column value in your **sales_sequence_profile** table against your meta_id = 1;

Comment: could you please look at my post at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325884/magento-2-3-4-how-to-trim-the-order-confirmation-number/325892?noredirect=1#comment466143_325892