# Magento 2 Order number increment

Tags: magento2, database, sql

By default, in **Magento 2** the order number starts from **100000001**. But if I want to increase it by **55555**.

So it would look like **100055555**, what would be the **SQL** query to directly modify the table which is responsible for this.

I am not looking for any extension or additional coding.

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101341/magento-2-what-is-the-correct-way-to-change-default-order-id , im sure you will find the correct answer to your question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to run the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 0055555;
```

I believe, that's what you're looking for.