# How come the order number comes up wrong in ShipWorks?

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping

I followed this [QA's method to customize the order number](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101341/magento-2-what-is-the-correct-way-to-change-default-order-id) on my recent Magento 2.3.1 migration. But when ShipWorks downloads the orders, they still start at `1`.

ShipWorks' support team called back and they are keying the `order_id` field for order numbers and not `increment_id`, which as we all know, is the Order Number in human speak. Once I test the effectiveness of updating the <kbd>sales_order</kbd>  table's auto_increment primary key, I'll post an answer.

Comment: If `order_id` is used, note that the "Order #" must be an `int` data type and must not have any other characters for this to work. If an order gets edited, magento adds a `-1` to the `increment_id`. This renders any workarounds void, as the `order_id` increments and gets out of sync with the `increment_id`/Order #. I sent feedback that this was a fatal flaw and that we'd look at other packages if they couldn't update with a timeline for the fix.